# Using a different face detector with dlib's landmark detector

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I am currently working on a python implementation of Adrian Rosebrock's video blink detector with dlib blog post:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/author/adrian/

Basically, I am using dlib's frontal face detector and passing the bounding box around the face to dlib's landmark detector as seen in this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUQEz.jpg

Sometimes dlib's frontal face detector doesn't find a face, but other face detectors like OpenCV's do. Adrian's blog made it sound like I could use openCV's frontal face detector and pass the bounding box along instead.

However when I do this the landmark detector can't find the eyes of the person correctly as seen in this photo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oztvG.jpg

Is there way I could use an alternative face detector with dlib's landmark detector? Or am I stuck using dlib's frontal face detector because the bounding box passed by a different face detector will be ever so slightly incorrect for the dlib landmark detector?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I removed the "ML" tag since you're obviously programming in Python. Please consider reading the descriptions of the tags you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the images you are providing it just look like you are not passing the correct parameters to the plotting method. The results look correct, just upside-down.

Comment: You are correct, when converting the rectangle returned by openCV to a dlib.rectangle I had the top and bottom fields switched. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own face detector. You just have to use `dlib.rectangle()` function. First, find the bounding boxes from your face detector and after that map them to `dlib.rectangle(x,y,w,h)`.

Then you can pass the bounding boxes from this list to `predictor(img, rect)`.